# GORM Criteria Query: Finding Children with specific properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

Have the following Domain modal:

```
class TransactionHeader {
  static hasMany = [details: TransactionDetail]
}

class TransactionDetail {
   static belongsTo = [header: TransactionHeader]
   Product product
}
```

I'm trying to write a criteria query that will return all the TransactionHeader rows that contain TransactionDetails with 2 different Products.  This is what I have so far and it isn't doing exactly what I'm after:

```
def list = TransactionHeader.withCriteria {
    details {
      and {
        eq("product", product1)
        eq("product", product2)
      }
    }
}
```

What's happening is it is return rows that contain at least 1 detail with 1 of the products.  I need rows that have 2 details, each with one of the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like you want to move details out of that, so actually

```
def list = TransactionHeader.withCriteria {
    and {
       details {
          eq("product", product1)
       }
       details {
          eq("product", product2)
       }
    }
}
```

Not sure how hibernate / gorm will deal this, though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the "in" statement in your criteria dsl?

```
def list = TransactionHeader.withCriteria {
    and {
       details {
          'in'("product", [product1, product2])
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: in processes as an OR which is not what I want.  I've already accepted the correct answer.

Comment: Got it, sorry I didn't realize the and constraint